# Error C2248 in MVSE12 with std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-studio-express

Good evening everyone !

I am trying to code a multi-threaded application in C++ with Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2012.

The idea us that the "main" function call a thread which will run "forever", with the task of updating an object.

This is the main :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>//debug only
#include <fstream> //debug only
#include "dataCollectorFTL.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    dataCollectorFTL dataCollector1;

    //Launch thread which will run forever and get the data flows
    dataCollector1.runDataCollector();


    while(true){
        //application running    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the ".h" of the class

```
#ifndef DATACOLLECTORFTL_H_INCLUDED
#define DATACOLLECTORFTL_H_INCLUDED


#include <thread>

class dataCollectorFTL {

public:

    void runDataCollector();

    void getData(); 


    //constructor, destructor
    dataCollectorFTL();
    ~dataCollectorFTL();

private:
    HANDLE hProcess;
    std::thread dataCollectorThread;

};

#endif // DATACOLLECTORFTL_H_INCLUDED
```

And finally the ".cpp"

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include "dataCollectorFTL.h"


void dataCollectorFTL::runDataCollector(){

    //lauch a non-local thread
    dataCollectorThread = std::thread(&dataCollectorFTL::getData, this);
}


void dataCollectorFTL::getData(){
    //some stuff    

}

dataCollectorFTL::dataCollectorFTL(){
    //some stuff
}

dataCollectorFTL::~dataCollectorFTL(){

    dataCollectorThread.join();
}
```

The problem is that when I run it, it gaves me this two errors :

> Error 1   error C2248: 'std::thread::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class  'std::thread'  c:\users\damien\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\recherche\recherche\datacollectorftl.h    233 1   Recherche
>
> Error 4   error C2248: 'std::thread::thread' : cannot access private member declared in class  'std::thread'  c:\users\damien\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\recherche\recherche\datacollectorftl.h    233 1   Recherche

To save time, I can tell you that :

- include  in the .h doesn't change anything
- The content of the runDataCollector methods doesn't change anything. Even if it is empty I still got the problem
- std::thread dataCollectorThread can be public or private, it doesn't change anything

If I don't declare as a member of the class, I have a crash of the program because I don't join() the thread in runDataCollector(). And I don't want to join it, has getData() is a while(true) function where it gets data from another soft.

Thank you very much for the time you spent reading this, and thank you again for any help.

Comment: You're trying to copy-assign `dataCollectorFTL` somewhere. Of course not in the code you posted.

Comment: Both errors highlight line #233 in `datacollectorftl.h` . Could you please post that exact line? You've made it difficult to see where the compiler is complaining.

Comment: The code presented looks fine; http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2c1af3a84792c771. Are you sure you are not copying the parent `dataCollectorFTL` class somewhere, that would cause the error you see. Make it's copy and assignment operators private and the error messages will help diagnose the location of the copy. If not, a [mcve] would help here.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help.
Unfortunaltely, John Burger's help didn't solve the problem.
I am afraid not to understand completely what is copy-assign.
line 233 is the end of the class in the .h. In term of code, it's '};'
I will give you the full code. However it's kinda messy, and for early test I didn't put anything private. Please excuse such a bad coding.

Comment: The main : http://paste2.org/jsePOO5v
The .h : http://paste2.org/gAYAX2CU
The .cpp : http://paste2.org/gDBD9e3V

Answer (score 1):

I understand that it was some time ago, but I bumped into the problem with same symptoms, and was able to solve it since my compilator (VC110 shipped with VS2012) was a little bit more verbose about what's the problem, so maybe it will help somebody.

I wanted to use this struct:

```
struct WorkerThreadContext
{
   std::thread worker;
   ... some other attributes ...
}
```

in a std::vector. Build resulted in error message:

> d:\code\testroom\t2\t2\t2.cpp(16): error C2248:
>   'std::thread::thread' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::thread'
>
> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\thread(73) : see declaration of 'std::thread::thread'
>
> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\thread(32) : see declaration of 'std::thread'
>
> This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function WorkerThreadContext::WorkerThreadContext(const WorkerThreadContext &)'

Key part is the last sentence - it seems that compiler has a problem to generate implicit copy constructor for my struct, so I changed it to:

```
struct WorkerThreadContext
{
   std::thread worker;
   ... other attributes ...
   WorkerThreadContext() {}
   // added explicit copy constructor
   WorkerThreadContext(const WorkerThreadContext&) {}
};
```

and was able to compile the code.

Edit: I almost forget. The reason why the compiler has a problem with this is, that std::thread objects cannot be copied ([std::thread::operator=](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/operator=/)) so the compiler has a problem to construct implicit copy constructor, because it doesn't know how to copy the 'std::thread' object. Which also means, that if you put there explicit copy constructor as the one I wrote, your members (including the 'std::thread' one become invalid). You may (and you should) of course initialize the rest of the struct, however std::thread will remain uninitialized, because you cannot copy it.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a function in to the `std::thread` constructor, it needs to be callable from file-scope. In other words, if it's a member function, that function needs to be `static`. You can still pass in `this` - just tell the function to expect it.

In other words:

- Add the following to the class declaration:

  ```
  private:

     void getData(); // Moved from public!

     static void myGetData(DataCollectorFTL *ftl);
  ```
- Write `myGetData`:

  ```
  void DataCollectorFTL::myGetData(DataCollectorFTL *ftl) {
      ftl->getData();
  } // DataCollectorFLT::myGetData(ftl)
  ```
- Change the call to `std::thread()`

  ```
  //lauch a non-local thread
  dataCollectorThread = std::thread(&myGetData, this);
  ```